# Where Can I find tutorials on Secure Networking in iOS Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, authentication, networking

Please find below list of topics :

1. How Can I authenticate servers for initial setup i.e authenticating with the help of Certificates on both ends server & iphone ?
2. How Can I use AuthenticationChallenge Mechanism in RESTFull services ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can find all information regarding how network works and in detail check this link.

[About Networking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Moreover for securing network , with **SSL** and **TSL**

[SecureNetworking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/SecureNetworking/SecureNetworking.html)

- According to your question you can also find detail regarding which certificate you can find information on samepage with finding **Install Certificates Correctly**

Check this line ,

> When your server accepts a connection encrypted with TLS or SSL, it
>   provides two things: your server’s SSL certificate and a complete
>   chain of SSL certificates, beginning with your server’s certificate
>   and ending with a certificate signed by one of the trusted anchor
>   certificates recognized by the operating system. If there are
>   certificates missing in your chain, you’ll get this error because the
>   certificates earlier in the chain cannot be verified without the
>   certificates later in the chain.